# How to execute code if the difference in the value of a variable is over 20

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I'm trying to see if `var1` is not equal to `var2`, but has top be greater than it by 20 or more to execute the code.

I currently have:

```
if (var1 != var2) {
    // need to put what happens if var2 is 20 or more greater than var1
}
else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add condition this on loop

```
if (var1 != var2) {

// need to put what happens if var2 is 20 or more greater than var1
if(var1 - var2 >= 20){

}else{

}
}else{

}
```

Comment: no, if var 1 is 200 and var2 is 201, i dont want it to go off, but if var1 is 200 and var2 is 220 i want it to go off.

Comment: I don't think this satisfies the question yet as var2 has to be greater or equal to 20 as compared to var1, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract the two and compare the difference to 20.

```
// if var2 is 20 or more greater than var1
if (var2 - var1 >= 20) {
     // do something here
} else {
     // something else here
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be var2 that is greater than equal to 20 as compared to var1, as stated in the question.

Comment: @user11657407 - My interpretation of the question was as I originally answered, but I now see a comment from the OP that says "if var1 is 200 and var2 is 220 i want it to go off" so I've modified it to test if `var2` is 20 or more greater than `var1`.  The question is pretty confusing in that regard, using an "it" pronoun that is not clear which they mean and could easily be interpreted either way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do what you wanted.

```
//Check if the difference between var2 and var1 is greater than or equal to 20
if(var2 - var1 >= 20){
    //Insert Code here
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `var1 != var2`.  If `var2 - var1 >= 20`, then there's no way that `var1 === var2` anyway.  So, that first comparison is unnecessary.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for pointing that out. Thinking more about it, that seems seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if(Math.Abs(var1 +- var2) >= 20){
//do code
}
```

Comment: Your test passes if var1 is more than 20 less than var2.  You don't want `Math.abs()` here.

Comment: OP wants only the var1 to be strictly greater than var2, no need of absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you wanted

```js
if (var2-var1 >= 20) {
    // Insert code here
}
```

But if you want to check both if var2 and var1 are apart by 20 atleast one could be lesser one could be greater, then

```js
if (Math.abs(var2-var1) >= 20) {
    // Insert code here
}
```